# RBF kernel not working for SVM

Tags: svm

I was trying to use RBF kernel for a 3 way classification of data. However, the problem is that when I use RBF kernel all the examples are classified as one class.
Here is the confusion matrix for RBF kernel

```
[[ 0  0 19]
 [ 0  0 12]
 [ 0  0 19]]
```

But when I use linear kernel i get a decent accuracy of 80%.
I tried the suggestions mentioned in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125353/output-of-scikit-svm-in-multiclass-classification-always-gives-same-label) answer but none of them helped.
The dataset contains 500 samples and I have used 3 features. T always thought that when the features are lesser than number of samples rbf will give the best performance but this doesn't seem the case here.

Comment: You're not really giving enough information here - how are you doing the training? Perhaps you're not including sufficiently broad values for the kernel width?

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate the meaning of the statement "how are you doing the training"?